# Core-Plot how to pack data

Tags: iphone, datasource, core-plot

I was wondering how I need to prepare the data so it is ready for core-plot.

- one line per year
- dayOfYear in the x-axis
- value on the y-axis

My x-axis has 366 points (Each day of the year). At the moment I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
 2009 (year) =     {
        151 (dayofyear) = 5 (value);
        192 = 25;
        206 = 5;
        234 = 20;
        235 = 20;
        255 = 20;
        262 = 10;
        276 = 10;
        290 = 10;
        298 = 7;
        310 = 1;
        338 = 3;
        354 = 5;
        362 = 5;
    };
    2010 =     {
        114 = 7;
        119 = 3;
        144 = 7;
        17 = 5;
        187 = 10;
        198 = 7;
        205 = 10;
        212 = 10;
        213 = 20;
        215 = 5;
        247 = 10;
        248 = 10;
        256 = 10;
        262 = 7;
        264 = 10;
        277 = 10;
        282 = 3;
        284 = 7;
        47 = 5;
        75 = 7;
        99 = 7;
    };
    2011 =     {
        260 = 10;
    };
```

I think core-plot needs an array doesn't it? How would you pack this to be the most efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually changed the structure to this.
A dictionary with the year as the key and an array for each point containing the dayofyear and the value.

```
2009 =     (
                (354,5),
                (338,3),
                (234,20),
                (298,7),
                (192,25)
)
```

That way the implementation was very easy

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    return [[[self.data objectForKey:plot.identifier] objectAtIndex: index] objectAtIndex: fieldEnum];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of data structure is completely up to you. You already have the data in a dictionary, so keep that. Implement the following method in your datasource:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

Assuming you have a separate plot for each year, use the `plot` parameter to select the appropriate year dictionary from the data dictionary. Use the `fieldEnum` parameter to determine whether the plot is asking for the x or y value and the `index` parameter to decide which value in the list to return.

For instance (assuming all values in the dictionaries are stored as NSNumber objects and you're using a scatter plot):

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSDictionary *year = // retrieve the year dictionary based on the plot parameter

    NSDictionary *yearData = [year objectAtIndex:index];

    NSNumber *num = nil;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            num = [yearData objectForKey:@"dayofyear"];
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            num = [yearData objectForKey:@"value"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return num;
}
```